# Mocking WebClient post method is failing

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I could find several questions regarding mocking a WebClient object. But I still have problems when doing a post with a body and having multiple header values. I'm just using Mockito.

```
public Boolean addNote(AlarmModel model) {
        ServiceDTO dto = mapper(model);

        return webClient.post()
                .uri("/service/api/addNotes")
                .headers(getHttpHeaders(dto.getHeader()))
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(Mono.just(dto.getBody()), ServiceBodyDTO.class)
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, this::handleStatusCodeError)
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, this::handleStatusCodeError)
                .bodyToMono(Boolean.class)
                .block();
    }
```

And this is how I am mocking the behavior of the post method.

```
        when(webClientMock.post()).thenReturn(requestBodyUriMock);
        when(requestBodyUriMock.uri(anyString())).thenReturn(requestBodyMock);
        
        when(requestHeadersMock.headers(any())).thenReturn(requestHeadersMock);

        when(requestBodyMock.accept(any())).thenReturn(requestBodyMock);
        when(requestBodyMock.contentType(any())).thenReturn(requestBodyMock);
        when(requestBodyMock.bodyValue(any())).thenReturn(requestHeadersMock);
        when(requestHeadersMock.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseMock);
        when(responseMock.bodyToMono(Boolean.class))
                .thenReturn(Mono.just(true));
```

But, when I execute this test case, it fails at the line having ***retrieve()*** And the exception is `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Did I miss anything here? TIA.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mocking-webclient#mockwebserver

Comment: Yeah, I checked that already. I'll need to do integration testing for that. I was trying to do unit testing.

Comment: unit testing webclient has very low ROI, its API is not designed for that, you're much better off with integration testing only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with @Martin's comment that *unit testing webclient has very low ROI.*

I would recommend [WireMock](https://wiremock.org) which provides very good API for testing web clients. Here are some examples

```
stubFor(post("/service/api/addNotes")
        .withHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, containing(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
        .willReturn(aResponse()
                .withStatus(200)
                .withBody("true")
        )
);

StepVerifier.create(service.addNote(note))
        .expectNextCount(1)
        .verifyComplete();
```

You could easily test both positive and negative scenarios by providing different stubs

```
stubFor(post("/service/api/addNotes")
        .withHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, containing(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
        .willReturn(aResponse()
                .withStatus(500)
        )
);
```

test retry logic using [Scenarios](https://wiremock.org/docs/stateful-behaviour/) or even simulate timeouts using [Delays](https://wiremock.org/docs/simulating-faults/)

ps

not sure why you are using `block` but my example is using `StepVerifier` and assumes that `addNote` returns `Mono<Boolean>`

Answer (score 3):

This is what works for me, not too different from yours. You might want to compare and feedback :)

```
@Mock
private WebClient webClient;

@Mock
WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec requestBodyUriSpec;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Mock
WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec requestHeadersSpec;

@Mock
WebClient.RequestBodySpec requestBodySpec;

@Mock
WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec;

given(getWebClient()).willReturn(webClient);
given(webClient.post()).willReturn(requestBodyUriSpec);
given(requestBodyUriSpec.uri(anyString())).willReturn(requestBodySpec);
given(requestBodySpec.headers(any())).willReturn(requestBodySpec);      
given(requestBodySpec.contentType(any())).willReturn(requestBodySpec);
given(requestBodySpec.accept(any())).willReturn(requestBodySpec);
given(requestBodySpec.bodyValue(any())).willReturn(requestHeadersSpec);
given(requestHeadersSpec.retrieve()).willReturn(responseSpec);
```

Comment: Thank you. You helped me leave a few hairs on my head.