# Spring webflux junit test onErrorResume with Unauthorized exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, spring-webflux, junit5

I have below service method which is using spring webflux to request webclient to get the response.

```
public Mono<String> fetch(String body, HttpHeaders headers, String correlationId) {
    Mono<String> response;
    try {
        response = postRequest(URI, headers, body);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        throw new ExceptionHandler(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ErrorCode.REQUEST_ERROR);
    }
    return response;
}

private Mono<String> postRequest(String uri, HttpHeaders headers, String body) {
    return getStringMono(uri, headers, body).onErrorResume(exception -> {
        if (exception instanceof WebClientResponseException.Unauthorized) {
            accessTokenCache.invalidate(ACCESS_TOKEN);
            String updatedToken = accessTokenCache.getIfPresent(ACCESS_TOKEN);
            headers.replace(AUTHORIZATION, Collections.singletonList(updatedToken));
            return getStringMono(uri, headers, body);
        } else {
            log.info(exception.getMessage());
            throw new ExceptionHandler(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ErrorCode.REQUEST_ERROR);
        }
    });
}

private Mono<String> getStringMono(String uri, HttpHeaders headers, String body) {
    return webClient.post().uri(uri).headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.addAll(headers))
            .body(Mono.just(body), String.class).retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);
}
```

I want to test the above code using junit, and wrote the below testcase

```
@Test
    public void testUnauthorizedException() {
        RequestBodyUriSpec reqBodyUriMock = mock(WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec.class);
        RequestBodySpec reqBodyMock = mock(WebClient.RequestBodySpec.class);
        RequestHeadersSpec reqHeaderMock = mock(WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec.class);
        ResponseSpec responseSpec = mock(WebClient.ResponseSpec.class);
        when(webClient.post()).thenReturn(reqBodyUriMock);
        when(reqBodyUriMock.uri(ArgumentMatchers.<String>notNull())).thenReturn(reqBodyMock);
        when(reqBodyMock.headers(any())).thenReturn(requestBodySpec);
        when(reqBodyMock.body(any(), eq(String.class))).thenReturn(reqHeaderMock);
        when(reqHeaderMock.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpec);


        ExchangeFunction exchangeFunction = mock(ExchangeFunction.class);
        given(exchangeFunction.exchange(any(ClientRequest.class))).willReturn(Mono.error(WebClientResponseException.Unauthorized.create(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), "Unauthorized", null, null, null)));

        when(responseSpec.bodyToMono(ArgumentMatchers.<Class<String>>notNull()))
                .thenThrow(WebClientResponseException.Unauthorized.create(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), "Unauthorized", null, null, null));

        ExceptionHandler exception = assertThrows(
                ExceptionHandler.class, () -> client.fetch(body, headers, correlationId));
        assertEquals(ErrorCode.REQUEST_ERROR, exception.getMessage());
    }
```

The test is not covering the Unauthorized exception if block instead its coming out and going into catch block of fetch method, how to refactor the test to cover Unauthorized exception if block?

Comment: Mocking WebClient internals could be tricky and error prone. It could be hard to cover all cases. I would suggest to look at wiremock for testing clients. Check this post for some details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71356276/mocking-webclient-post-method-is-failing/71359000#71359000

Comment: As for your code. Wrapping  ‘postRequest‘ into try-catch will not work - not sure what do you want to achieve there but you need to use reactive operators instead. Also instead of throwing exception - return ‘Mono.error‘

Comment: Thanks @Alex, the posted link was really helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With the use of wiremock could able to stub the webclient, below is the working test

@Rule
public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(wireMockConfig().port(8888));

```
@Test
public void testUnauthorizedException() {
    String response = FileHelper.readFile(DATA + "Response.json");
    RequestBodyUriSpec reqBodyUriMock = mock(WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec.class);
    RequestBodySpec reqBodyMock = mock(WebClient.RequestBodySpec.class);
    RequestHeadersSpec reqHeaderMock = mock(WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec.class);
    ResponseSpec responseSpec = mock(WebClient.ResponseSpec.class);
    when(webClient.post()).thenReturn(reqBodyUriMock);
    when(reqBodyUriMock.uri(ArgumentMatchers.<String>notNull())).thenReturn(reqBodyMock);
    when(reqBodyMock.headers(any())).thenReturn(requestBodySpec);
    when(reqBodyMock.body(any(), eq(String.class))).thenReturn(reqHeaderMock);
    when(reqHeaderMock.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpec);
    
    when(responseSpec.bodyToMono(ArgumentMatchers.<Class<String>>notNull()))
        .thenReturn(Mono.error(Unauthorized.create(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), "Unauthorized", null, null, null)))
            .thenReturn(Mono.just(response));
            
    stubFor(post(URI)
            .willReturn(unauthorized()
                    .withStatus(401)
            ).willReturn(aResponse()
                    .withStatus(200)
                    .withBody("true"))
    );

    StepVerifier.create(client.fetch(body, headers, correlationId))
            .expectNextMatches(response -> response.equals(response))
            .expectComplete()
            .verify();
}
```

Comment: If you are using wiremock you don’t need mockito mocks for webclient. I would rather use wiremock stubs only