# How to cover WebFlux Webclient 4XX and 5XX Error Scenario's using Mockito mock

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

**I have been trying to cover webclient testcases for 4xx and 5xx Error responses using Mockito mock but unable to cover them.**

Below is the method trying to cover :

```
 public Mono<String> getAzureToken() {

    log.info(" Getting azure token");

    AtomicReference<Long> startTime = new AtomicReference<>();

    if (expiresAt != null && !this.isTokenExpired()) {
        return Mono.just(this.token);
    }

    return webClient.post().uri(serviceProperties.getAzureTokenUri())
            .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(CLIENT_ID, serviceProperties.getClientId())
                          .with(CLIENT_SECRET, serviceProperties.getClientSecret())
                          .with(GRANT_TYPE, CLIENT_CREDENTIALS))
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatusCode::is4xxClientError, (clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(Map.class)
                    .flatMap(resp -> {
                        String serviceResponse = (resp != null) ? resp.toString() : EMPTY;
                        log.error(
                                """
                                Exception(is4xxClientError) occurred while getting Azure token  \
                                 Returned Response Code [{}], Response from Azure  \
                                service {} \
                                """,
                                clientResponse.statusCode(),
                                serviceResponse);
                        return Mono.error(
                                new serviceException(ApiErrorCode.POST_AZURE_SERVICE_ERROR, serviceResponse,
                                                            clientResponse.statusCode(),
                                                            ServiceCodes.AZURE_SERVICE_CODE));
                    })))
            .onStatus(HttpStatusCode::is5xxServerError, (clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(Map.class)

                    .flatMap(resp -> {
                        String serviceResponse = (resp != null) ? resp.toString() : EMPTY;
                        log.error(
                                """
                                Exception(is5xxServerError) occurred while getting Azure token \
                                 Returned Response Code {}, Response from Azure \
                                service {} \
                                """,
                                clientResponse.statusCode(),
                                serviceResponse);
                        return Mono.error(
                                new serviceException(ApiErrorCode.POST_AZURE_SERVICE_ERROR, serviceResponse,
                                                            clientResponse.statusCode(),
                                                            ServiceCodes.AZURE_SERVICE_CODE));
                    })))
            .bodyToMono(Map.class).map(response -> {
                this.token = (String)response.get("access_token");

                log.debug("accessToken " + token);
                long expiresIn = Long.valueOf((String) response.get("expires_on"));

                this.expiresAt = new Date(expiresIn * 1000);
                log.debug(" expires at :" + expiresAt);

                return token;
            })
            .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(serviceProperties.getAzureTimeoutValueInMillis()))
            .contextCapture()
            .onErrorResume(e -> {
                log.error("""
                                  Error occurred while calling Azure for token   \
                                  Exception : {}, stackTrace: {},  Message {}\
                                  """,
                          e.getStackTrace(), ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e),
                          StringUtil.encodeCRLF(e.getMessage()));
                return Mono.error(e);
            }).doOnSubscribe(x -> startTime.set(System.nanoTime()))
            .doFinally(x -> {
                final long milliSecTaken = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime() - startTime.get());
                log.info("Time taken by Azure token call  -> : {} milliseconds.", milliSecTaken);
            });


}
```

TestCase as below

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
```

public class MyCloudServiceCallerTest {

```
@Mock
private WebClient webClientMock;

@InjectMocks
MyCloudServiceCaller myCloudServiceCaller;

@MockBean
private ObservationRegistry observationRegistry;

@Mock
private WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec requestBodyUriSpecMock;

@Mock
private WebClient.RequestHeadersUriSpec requestHeadersUriSpecMock;

@Mock
private WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec requestHeadersSpecMock;

@Mock
private CustomMinimalForTestResponseSpec responseSpecMock;

@Mock
serviceProperties serviceProperties;

@Test
void shouldFailsWhenHttpStatus5xx() {
    when(serviceProperties.getAzureTokenUri()).thenReturn("https://login.microsoftonline.com/ghsggsfaddararra/oauth2/token");
    when(serviceProperties.getClientId()).thenReturn("SomeClientId");
    when(serviceProperties.getClientSecret()).thenReturn("SomeSecret");
    //given
    when(webClientMock.post()).thenReturn(requestBodyUriSpecMock);
    when(requestBodyUriSpecMock.uri(anyString()))
            .thenReturn(requestBodyUriSpecMock);
    when(requestBodyUriSpecMock.body(any())).thenReturn(requestHeadersSpecMock);
    when(requestHeadersSpecMock.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpecMock);

    when(responseSpecMock.getStatus()).thenReturn(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);

    when(responseSpecMock.onStatus(any(Predicate.class), any(Function.class))).thenCallRealMethod();

    //when + Then
    Mono<String> result = myCloudServiceCaller.getAzureToken();

    StepVerifier.create(result)
            .expectNext("newToken")
            .verifyComplete();
}


abstract class CustomMinimalForTestResponseSpec implements WebClient.ResponseSpec {

    public abstract HttpStatus getStatus();

    public WebClient.ResponseSpec onStatus(Predicate<HttpStatusCode> statusPredicate, Function<ClientResponse, Mono<? extends Throwable>> exceptionFunction) {
        if (statusPredicate.test(this.getStatus())) exceptionFunction.apply(ClientResponse.create(HttpStatus.OK).build()).block();
        return this;
    }

}
```

}

**Trying to cover 4XX and 5XX errors blocks but its not working. looking for solution without using Wiremock and Mockserver **

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mocking WebClient post method is failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71356276/mocking-webclient-post-method-is-failing)